# Reproducing an hmac operation in python from the javascript reference case

Tags: javascript, python, hmac

I have a fragment of javascript that operates properly:

```
let seed = '319aa8124bbcddac2bae8438cfd5e658aeca56d524736739622dfb0a09942b22';
let salt = '0000000000000000004d6ec16dafe9d8370958664c1dc422f452892264c59526';
// 1. HMAC_SHA256(message=seed, key=salt)  
const hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(seed), salt);
let foo = hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
console.log("foo", hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));  //foo fe6a57f08b9970b7cd497e627afac956203a8ef829d2d97c7967775c1c0b6f6a
```

I try to reproduce it in python:

```
seed = "319aa8124bbcddac2bae8438cfd5e658aeca56d524736739622dfb0a09942b22"
salt = "0000000000000000004d6ec16dafe9d8370958664c1dc422f452892264c59526"
hm = hmac.new(str.encode(seed), b'', hashlib.sha256)
hm.update(salt.encode("utf-8"))
h = hm.hexdigest()
print(h)   # returns 01703d8db07432ca416151099533b60baea7a6450fc5b88788c7ca9af921b4a1
```

but the result is incorrect.

I think the step I'm missing is the `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(seed)` operation that occurs in the javascript. I don't understand what that is doing to the seed value.  I try to `console.log()` that value but it returns a complicated object that I don't comprehend.

So my questions are:

1. what is that function doing to the the `seed`
2. how to do the equivalent in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These algorithms work on raw bytes. Your seed is representing those bytes in hexadecimal, i.e. `31` is one byte, `9a` is another. `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse` parses the hexadecimal to bytes. The equivalent in Python is with `codecs.decode("...", "hex")`.

The salt also looks like hexadecimal but your JS doesn't parse it as such, so I've just treated it as UTF8 in the python as well.

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import codecs

seed = codecs.decode(b"319aa8124bbcddac2bae8438cfd5e658aeca56d524736739622dfb0a09942b22", "hex")
salt = u"0000000000000000004d6ec16dafe9d8370958664c1dc422f452892264c59526".encode("utf8")
hm = hmac.new(salt, seed, hashlib.sha256)
h = hm.hexdigest()
print(h)   # returns fe6a57f08b9970b7cd497e627afac956203a8ef829d2d97c7967775c1c0b6f6a
```

Comment: thanks for a clear explanation. Sorted it all out.